# Using STDIN in a Linux init script

Tags: python, linux, stdin, init

I'm currently working on an embedded system that needs to read keyboard input (Actually - it needs to read a keyboard-emulated barcode scanner).

I'm using a SheevaPlug with Debian Squeeze for the hardware part, and I'm using a pretty basic init script that fires a python program that's in charge of doing the business logic.

It's that script that needs to read keyboard input.

We've worked on development versions that were basically full featured computers, with a screen and stuff, and it worked pretty OK - but it's not really acceptable -, but here I don't really grasp what's wrong (Although I admit that I kinda expected it).

So I'd like to know how it would be possible to somehow connect the keyboard to my script's STDIN when init starts it.

Alternatively, I'd be interested if someone knows a python library that would allow me to bypass the problem entirely and read directly from input/eventX.

Thanks in advance

Comment: an init script? You want to read a barcode while the system is booting? You mean a shell script?

Comment: I start the script on runlevel 2 (Last, so sshd and stuff have priority to start). If it's not the proper way of handling this, I'd be very interested in suggestions!

Comment: Ok. Was just wondering about the terminology. Those "init" scripts are just shell scripts which happen to get invoked by init. Shouldn't be a problem to read from keyboard, since init's default stdin is the system console. However, you'd need some way to trigger the barcode scanner to actually do a scan. Those init/rc scripts are also generally NOT executed by a simple login. Usually at boot time or when changing run levels.

Comment: Well, right now, for testing purposes, I'm using a standard keyboard (As my barcode scanner is recognized as a HID device), they work the same way. But my issue is, my keyboard does not appear to be connected to the system console. However, the SheevaPlug's JTAG port is.

Comment: You could just have the script read from whatever /dev file your keyboard shows up under, rather than defaulting to stdin. That'd let you do the debugging. if you're sshing in, it'd probably /dev/pty/xxx for whatever your login session's pseudoterminal is.

Comment: Oops, what I meant by "Debugging" was actually getting the program to run properly (Which includes reading barcodes once it booted) on the Plug computer. If I want to debug something else I can always do it on  another computer. However, your suggestion of reading /dev is interesting, but ... how do I do so? I've tried reading them event pseudofiles, but I'd like to know if there exists a simple way? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Hum your suggestion was quite inspirational, it happens that I can collect keyboard input from tty0, tty1 and (I guess) so on. However, would you happen to.. know why? I'm never really confortable with using something that I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (but be carefull /dev/input/event0 can be changed in place of repluging multiple USB HID-devices):

```
import struct

inputDevice = "/dev/input/event0" #keyboard on my system
inputEventFormat = 'iihhi'
inputEventSize = 16

file = open(inputDevice, "rb") # standard binary file input
event = file.read(inputEventSize)
while event:
  (time1, time2, type, code, value) = struct.unpack(inputEventFormat, event)
  print type,code,value
  event = file.read(inputEventSize)
file.close()


        def getUSBHIDs(self):
    s=getExecOutput('cat /proc/bus/input/devices')
    events=[]
    for i in range(len(s)):
        m=re.search('^.*Handlers=kbd.*event(?P<name>[0-9]+).*$',s[i])
        if m:
            events+=['/dev/event'+m.group('name')]
    return events
```

Comment: And would you know of a handy way of knowing what eventx the keyboard/ barcode reader is connected to?